# Highcharts transform JSON into data without losing informations

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I got a JSON with this format :

```
[{"date":1508473800525,"total":150,"class1":55,"class2":36},{...},{...}]
```

I want to use it in this example : https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/responsive

The input data is in this form :

```
[[1508473800525,150],[...]]
```

In order to have the same input I transform my json with a foreach and I push into an array like that

```
array.push([JSON.parse(elementObject["date"]), JSON.parse(elementObject["total"])])
```

It works but when I use it in my charts :

```
series : [{ data : array }]
```

I can not access to class1 and class2.

How can I do it in another way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save `class1` and `class2` properties to a particular point object in the data array. Each point will be an object like that:

```
  {
    x: jsonPoint.date,
    y: jsonPoint.total,
    class1: jsonPoint.class1,
    class2: jsonPoint.class2
  }
```

This approach allows you to access `class1` and `class2` in each data point.

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bfpvo324/1/

Answer (score 1):

From your code, you're not pushing `class1` and `class2` to the array. You're better off using `Object.keys` to make sure all the properties in your object are retained.

```
const responseJson = '[{"date":1508473800525,"total":150,"class1":55,"class2":36},{...},{...}]';

const dataForChart = JSON.parse(responseJson)
.map(obj => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return keys.reduce((f, c) => {
    f.push(obj[c]);
    return f;
  }, [])
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I should obtain something like [1508473800525,150,55,36], then i can keep only the first two values for my series but how can I can I access to the others  when I click for example on the data displayed?